# Pipe data to plutil

Tags: json, node.js, unix, pipe, plist

I have this bash script that takes the `plist` prop from `package.json` and I would like to pass it to plutil

```
cat package.json | ./node_modules/.bin/json "plist" | plutil -convert xml1 -o Info.plist
```

Instead of creating a temp file and deleting it.

```
cat package.json | ./node_modules/.bin/json "plist" > ./plist.json
plutil -convert xml1 ./plist.json -o ./MyApp.app/Contents/Info.plist
rm ./plist.json
```

Isn't the point of piping to prevent this ^?

Comment: Did you try adding `-` to the end of your `plutil` command line? According to the man page for it that needs to be added where the input file argument goes to let `plutil` know to read from stdin. Also, are you getting a specific error of some kind or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `cat package.json | plutil  -convert xml1 -r -o - -- -`

Here you another useful snippet. It replaces some plist elements which are not supported by json with strings.

```
security cms -D -i embedded.mobileprovision | sed -Ee 's#<(\/)?dat[ae]>#<\1string>#g' | plutil  -convert json -r -o - -- -
```